# how to transfer query string to controller's action in unit test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vs-unit-testing-framework

i have an Mvc controller which looks like:

```
public class PaymentController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ApiReturn()
    {
        var notify_id = Request.QueryString["notify_id"];
        return null;
    }
}
```

how do i transfer the query string "notify_id" when i do unit test for this ApiReturn, my unit test for this action is like below:

```
[TestClass]
public class PaymentControllerUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestApiReturn()
    {
        var paymentController = new PaymentController();
        paymentController.ApiReturn();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you doing public ActionResult ApiReturn(int notify_id) ??

Comment: Have you tried [Mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)?

Comment: Mvc knows how to parse the function parameters from the querystring, so you should be able to do as @ASG. Also it is a bad practice to tie your controller code to the HttpContext if you want it to be unit tested properly or otherwise you will be a in mockup hell, refer to http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2010/08/19/Dont-mock-HttpContext.

Comment: @ASG, the query string is just for simplifying my issue, Actually, what i wanna retrive includes QueryString, Form etc. thks.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin i have tried Moq Framework which meet my requirement and address my issue, thks so much.

Comment: @paulcheung That's a good framework, do not hesitate to read [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx/) on how to structure your unit tests.